# jump out of a JS variable encapsulation

Tags: javascript, html, sql, xss

I'm reading a boook on XSS attacks, and I've found an example about XSS filter evasion that is a little weird (IMHO).

This is the example text:

> Another possible injection point that could exist is when the developer uses unsanitized
>   user input as part of the generated HTML within a script element. For example:
>
> <script>
>   var query_string="**<XSS>**";
>   somefunction(query_string);
>   function somefunction {
>   ...
>   }
>   </script>
>
> It appears we have access to the inside of the JavaScript function. Let’s try adding some
>   quotes and see if we can jump out of the encapsulation:
>
> <script>
>   var query_string="**”<XSS>**";
>   somefunction(query_string);
>   function somefunction {
>   ...
>   }
>   <script>
>
> It worked, and also caused a JavaScript error in the process as shown in Figure 3.38.
>   Let’s try one more time, but instead of trying to inject HTML, let’s use straight
>   JavaScript. Because we are in a script tag anyway, why not use it to our advantage?
>
> <script>
>   var query_string="**”;alert(“XSS”);//**";
>   somefunction(query_string);
>   function somefunction {
>   ...
>   }
>   </script>

the **bold** text is what I suppose to be the user input, taken for example from a form.

Back to my question: is there any way that this kind of attack works? For example, suppose `somefunction(query_string)` is used to run some sql query, and `query_string` is a product name to search within the database. If inside the search function I create `sql_query = 'SELECT name FROM table WHERE name = "'+query_string+'"';`, I think there's no way to inject some string with quotes to "jump out of the encapsulation", i.e inputting `YAY";alert('hi');//` will not change the JS to this:

```
var query_string = [user input, in this case YAY";alert('hi');//]
function abc(query_string){
    sql_query = "select name FROM table WHERE name = 'YAY';
    alert('hi');//
    ....
}
```

Am I wrong? What do you think? Can you make me a simple example (if it possible) on how this kind of attack can make some sort of damages?

I thought about something like an online shop, but assuming the JS is not used on server side, the only thing this attack can do is modify the query string and then submit it to the server..

Hope you can understand what I wrote and what I'd like to understand, thanks, best regards.

Comment: why don't you try running some of this script yourself?

Comment: Why on Earth would you be constructing SQL queries on the client?

Comment: It's just to understand a possible type of attack, obviously it's not a good thing to do. :)

Comment: There's a big difference between [query strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and [SQL queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Queries). SQL queries aren't relevant to the example from your book, so I think you're confusing your terms.

Comment: XSS is often done via JavaScript injection, which is very similar to SQL injection. Both have their nuances, and both require being vigilant about sanitizing user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only look at the first line. The rest doesn't come into play in this xss example. It's a badly chosen example. So take this much simple example

```
var first_name="<XSS>";
```

In this example `<xss>` is user generated content. So your e.g. php code looks like this

```
var first_name="<? echo $firstName; ?>";
```

$firstName is taken from some database or something else, and was generated by the user who typed it into some textfield. Say the user typed: `";alert("XSS");//`. PHP will generate the following code

```
var first_name="";alert("XSS");//";
```

Pretty printed:

```
var first_name="";
alert("XSS");
//";
```

As you see the user was able to run his code `alert("XSS")` in every other users browser that visited the page. In this example nothing bad will happen except some alert box, but the user might inject some code that gets the cookie info and sends it to some server, so the attacker can steal someone's login session.

This same problem - forgetting to escape user generated content - also applies for creating sql queries, but this isn't related to this example. The creator of this example should have used `query_string` in his example, as it is obviously confusing.

Comment: I think what the author want to say it's a little bit different.. he tries to explain how to take control on the js function from a not sanitized user input, but I don't understand how it's possible without directly printing/echo-ing the value of the variable (as in your example, with php). Maybe I'm wrong, but I think it's impossible to inject some code while a variable is defined..What's your opinion? Thanks anyway for your useful example!

Comment: The problem of injections only occur when going from one language to another using strings. PHP to generate JS, JS to generate a SQL query, etc.. You should always use the proper escaping method, or sanitize the input, when dealing with these 'boundaries'. So as you said once the variable is defined the transition has already occurred, so any further injections can not occur, except when you make another transition, like e.g. using the variable to create a query. So never trust user input, or variables set by a script that you are not sure is secure.

Comment: So there's no way to take control of a function within the same language just by inputting a string whit code, right? With taking control I mean break the function in two parts, right where the input is taken in the original function, and then "discard" the rest of that using the input to add new malicious code. Thanks again for your patience in explaining me these things, your hints are really helpful to me.

Comment: No. JS know the variable contains a string. It will not try to evaluate that string as JS. It's just a block of memory to it.